# Using a string as a variable at run time

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string, which has been created at runtime. I want to use this string as a variable to store some data into it. How can I convert the string into a variable name?

Answer (score 56):

If you can forgive an @ sign in front of the variable name, the following will work:

```
variable_name = ... # determine user-given variable name
instance_variable_set("@#{variable_name}", :something)
```

This will create a variable named `@whatever`, with its value set to `:something`. The `:something`, clearly, could be anything you want. This appears to work in global scope, by declaring a spontaneous `Object` instance which binds everything (I cannot find a reference for this).

The `instance_variable_get` method will let you retrieve a value by name in the same manner.

```
instance_variable_get("@#{variable_name}")
```

Comment: I get `is not allowed as an instance variable name` for `instance_variable_set`. Rails 3.0.7.

Comment: FTR, you can also use `binding.local_variable_get("variable_name")` if you're on Ruby 2.1, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Little gotcha re B Seven's comment up there ^^, this can come about if you don't prepend the string with an `@` symbol

Answer (score 15):

You can use `eval()` for this provided that you've declared your variable first:

```
>> foo = []
>> eval("foo")[1] = "bar"
>> foo[1]
=> "bar"
```

Here are the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005948).

Answer (score 13):

Rather than do that directly, why not consider using a hash instead. The string would be the key, and the value you want to store would be the value. Something like this:

```
string_values = { }
some_string = params[:some_string]       # parameter was, say "Hello"
string_values[some_string] = 42
string_values                            # { 'Hello' => 42 }
some_number = string_values[some_string]
some_number                              # 42
```

This has a couple of benefits. First, it means you're not doing anything magic that might be hard to figure out later. Second, you're using a very common Ruby idiom that's used for similar functionality throughout Rails.

Comment: Huh? What if you just want to store "Hello" as a variable to use later. Where does the 42 come in? This seems overly complex...although admittedly I'm a Ruby newb.

Comment: That isn't what the questioner is asking. They are receiving a string value from somewhere at *runtime*, and wish to associate that string with a value. Sure, you could hack the system to create a variable with that string name (with the related caveat of error checking the string to ensure it's a valid identifier), but what I am suggesting is you use Ruby's simple, widely understood, and safe `Hash` to associate the string and the value together.

Answer (score 6):

Now simply using instance_variable_set method, you can create a instance variable at runtime.

```
instance_variable_set('@' + 'users', User.all)
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't mean to be negative, but tread carefully. Ruby gives you a lot of features for highly dynamic programming such as `define_method`, storing blocks as `Proc` objects to be called later, etc. Generally these are cleaner code and far safer. 99% of the time using `eval()` is a mistake.

And absolutely never use `eval()` on a string that contains user submitted input.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Watkins says, a lot of people might be quick to use eval() first thing and this would be a serious mistake. Most of the time you can use the technique described by Tack if you've taken care to use a class instance variable instead of a local one.

Local variables are generally not retrievable. Anything with the @ or @@ prefix is easily retrieved.