# How to create a variable name from the value of a string in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I want to create an instance variable in a controller to be used in the view:

```
foo = "bar"
instance_variable_set("#{foo}", "cornholio")
```

In the view, use @bar so that:

```
@bar => "cornholio"
```

This generates an error: `'bar' is not allowed as an instance variable name`

Working in Rails 3.1

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This `instance_variable_set("#{foo}", "cornholio")` needs to read `instance_variable_set("@#{foo}", "cornholio")`

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881239/using-a-string-as-a-variable-at-run-time-in-ruby-on-rails). Just tried it in my irb for Ruby 1.93; the post is from 2009.

Comment: seems like a really common mistake that could be auto-corrected by prepending a `@` if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, instance variable names always have to start with an `@` sigil.

Comment: +1 for terminology! Interestingly, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28magic%29 came before http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29 when Googling.

Comment: And that's exactly the reason why one could have thought that a method like instance_variable_set takes care of adding the "@"...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer for the same question but with an other thought. Because other people might ending up here looking for my answer here my question and solution:

I want to cal t(key, interpolation_var: value) in a method. where interpolation
_var: is different per translation.
solution(I have removed all non important information so only the solution to the problem is available. that's why the method looks unusefull :) ):

```
def some_function(key, interpolation_var, value)
  t(key, :#{interpolation_var} => value)
end
```