# Create dictionary name using part of a variable name

Tags: ruby

I need to create the name of a dictionary using the name of the current iteration of an array.

For example:

```
sites = ["google", "facebook", "twitter", "stackoverflow"]

sites.each do |site|

  #{site}_success_hash = {}  <-- I need the correct syntax for achieving this result.

   ... populate ... hash

end
```

So I would want 4 hashes named `google_success_hash`, etc.

I can't figure this out and it's driving me insane.

Comment: You should be storing your dictionaries in a super-dictionary, rather than making several global-level dictionaries.

Comment: Agreed; it's just a hash of hashes so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered to just nesting the hashes instead of keeping them in separate variables?

Something like this:

```
success_hash = {}
sites.each do |site|
  success_hash[site] = #populate hash
end
```

The thing you asked for could however be accomplished like this (assuming it's ok to use instance variables):

`instance_variable_set("@#{variable_name}", :something)`
(see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881239/using-a-string-as-a-variable-at-run-time-in-ruby-on-rails))

Comment: I didn't consider nesting my hashes. Thanks to you and the first 2 who gave me the idea. I got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all use symbols instead of strings for your sites:

```
sites = [:google, :facebook, :twitter, :stackoverflow]
```

Then I think this might work:

```
sites.each do |site|
  instance_variable_set("@#{site}_success_hash", {})
  # populate @site_success_hash
end
```

Notice that you're setting an instance variable here.