# Convert and String to Variable Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, variables

I would like to know if it is possible to convert a string in ruby to a variable. For example if I want the user to input a string with .get and then want to set the string they put to the name of a variable.

How can I make this work for example:

```
name=gets.chomp
name_var=#name as variable
name_var=Class.new
```

Thank you.

Comment: I believe your question has already been asked:
[Using a string as a variable at run time ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881239/using-a-string-as-a-variable-at-run-time

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem to me. Probably a hash might be a much better solution. Can you please explain why you want to do that.